# add span inside the a tag generated using link_to_action in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, hyperlink

I need to display the count of new appointments near to the appointment vertical menu in bubbles. i already calculated the count but the link is shown using link_to_action and i need to display the count in a span which should come inside the a tag.

```
<?php if(Session::get('side') == 'Appointments'){ ?>  
            <li><?php echo link_to_action('AdminController@anyShowAppointmentList', 'Appointments', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array('class'=>'active')); ?></li>
        <?php Session::forget('side'); }
 else { ?>
            <li><?php echo link_to_action('AdminController@anyShowAppointmentList', 'Appointments', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array()); ?><span class="update-plugins count-$appo"><span class="plugin-count">{{$appo}}</span></span></li>
        <?php } ?>
```

the variable $appo contains the count value. the above code displays the count below the menu item "appointments". did anyone knows how to display this span inside the "a" tag formed using link_to_action.

Answer (score 0):

ok..i solved it myself.. i added

```
HTML::decode(link_to_action('AdminController@anyShowAppointmentList', 'Appointments<span class="update-plugins count-$appo"><span class="plugin-count">'.$appo.'</span></span>', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array()));
```